# Google analytics tracking static/fixed IP web site without domain example.com

Tags: dns, google-analytics, html, static-ip-address

I have a web page hosted on my server with fixed and public IP as `http://193.175.3.112/quiz_v3.1/xxxx/xxxx/main.html`. I created a google analytics account with Url/domain name:`193.175.3.112` and copy paste the generated tracker code in my main.html page in `<head>` section:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


  ga('create', 'UA-48782448-1','193.175.3.112');

  ga('set','page','/quiz_v3.1/xxx/xxx/main.html');

  ga('send', 'pageview',{
  'page': '/quiz_v3.1/xxx/xxx/main.html',
  'title': 'Main page',
  'hitCallback': function() {
     alert('analytics.js done sending data'); // The alert is shown, hence no data in google analytics reporting page
  }
});

ga(function(tracker) {

  var defaultPage = tracker.get('page');
  alert(defaultPage);// shows "/quiz_v3.1/xxx/xxx/main.html"
});
</script>
```

Additionally  Status: Tracking Not Installed on Google Analytics Tracking code page.

**Can I track singe web page hosted on fixed/static public IP without domain, and then how to correct setup Google Analytics account?**

Comment: Have you tried simply copying the code Google gives you?  Remember anything you track takes 24 hours to show up in the standard reports.  Some data shows up immediately in the real-time reports but not that much.

Comment: Yes I have tried to simply copying and waited 2 days and nothing change :(. But the question is it possible to track a web page with static IP, if yes I will keep working on it, otherwise I need to create a domain:(

Comment: you should be able to.  Im just wondering if its something in all that extra code you have there that's causing the problem.  Have you tried just using the standard code?